# Printing labels in word, starting in a specific (offset) cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-word-2010, mail-merge

This is probably super simple and I'm just overlooking something... I hope.

I'm creating labels in Word 2010 and pulling the data from Excel 2010. I've got them laid out perfectly, but I need to reuse my label sheets in order to use up each label. We're printing labels for cabling in our datacenter, and these sheets are expensive, so we need to use each one completely.

So... is there an easy way for me to insert empty cells or specify an offset so that the first label can appear anywhere?

If there's not, can anyone suggest an alternative approach?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. In the document created during the mail merge process BEFORE the "Finish & Merge" step, you should see <> followed by your various name and address fields. Delete the items from each individual label you wish to skip.

If you already have the merged document, you can treat each row of labels as a row in a table. Click to select the entire row, then right-click inside the selection to access the "Insert" -> "Insert rows above"